# ServiceStack integration tests: ServiceStackHost.Instance has already been set

Tags: c#, unit-testing, servicestack, xunit.net

I am writing integration tests for ServiceStack with in-memory database and I ran into this exception: "System.IO.InvalidDataException ServiceStackHost.Instance has already been set" while trying to run multiple test classes together, each having its own AppHostHttpListenerBase. However, if I ran the test classes one at a time, it ran and passed without problems. One reason for having multiple classes is because I want to test the AppHost with different services/dependencies registered and also to group my tests logically.  Below is a general snippet of my tests. I would like to be able run all the test at one go.

```
public class TestClassOne : IDisposable
{
    string _endPoint = "http://localhost:54321/";
    AppHostHttpListenerBase _appHost;
    IDbConnectionFactory _dbConn = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);

    public TestClassOne()
    {
        _appHost = new UnitTestAppHost(_dbConn, ...){};
        _appHost.Init().Start(_endPoint);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
       ...
       using(var db = _dbConn.Open())
       {
          Assert.True(...);
       }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _appHost.Dispose();
        _appHost = null;
    }    
}

public class TestClassTwo : IDisposable
{
    string _endPoint = "http://localhost:54321/";
    AppHostHttpListenerBase _appHost;
    IDbConnectionFactory _dbConn = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(":memory:", SqliteDialect.Provider);

    public TestClassTwo()
    {
        _appHost = new UnitTestAppHost(...){};
        _appHost.Init().Start(_endPoint);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
       ...
       using(var db = _dbConn.Open())
       {
          Assert.True(...);
       }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _appHost.Dispose();
        _appHost = null;
    }    
}
```

I have tried running on another AppDomain, but it doesn't seems to be what I am looking for I think, because I need to do some Asserts on IDbConnection in the current running AppDomain (?), if that make any sense. Any suggestions on how I should be doing it? I'm using xUnit and Resharper's test runner btw.

Comment: I've never used it, so this might be a bit random, but have you tried changing the port on the end point for different tests to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: yup tried it before posting this question... same exception.

Comment: This is a bit dirty..and I'm guessing again, but based on the error, is the static instance property on ServiceHost still set, after you've called Dispose on it?  If so, have you tried resetting the `Instance` property of `ServiceHost` to null in your `Dispose`? The setter is protected, but you *might* be able to do it from your UnitTestAppHost class, which I'm assuming is derived from it.

Comment: just tried.... still the same exception. Thanks for the suggestion though :)

Comment: You can configure Nunit gui to run tests from different assemblies in different app domains.  I'd guess that you can probably do the same with Resharpers test runner (it may even let you run different test fixtures in their own app domain).  Is putting your tests for the different apphosts into seperate assemblies a viable option?

Comment: You can configure ResharperTest runner to run each test assembly in its own app domain (The docs mention MS&Nunit tests but I'm assuming it'll work for xUnit as well).  You'd have to split your tests so that each one is in a different assembly, but you should still be able to run them all in one go.  Obviously not ideal, but it might get it working if nobody comes up with a way to reset the host instance.  http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp80/Reference__Options__Tools__Unit_Testing.html  - Use separate app domain for each assembly with tests.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing this by creating an AppHostSetupFixture class with a public static AppHost variable.  Create a [SetUp] method that initializes your app host and a [TearDown] method that disposes it.  Use AppHostSetupFixture.AppHost in your test classes.

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class AppHostSetupFixture
{
    public static ServiceStackHost AppHost;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        AppHost = new BasicAppHost(typeof(FeatureService).Assembly)
        {
            ConfigureContainer = container =>
            {
                var l = new List<string>();
                l.Add(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Redis"].ConnectionString);
                container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new RedisManagerPool(l, new RedisPoolConfig() { MaxPoolSize = 40 }));
            }
        }
        .Init();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        AppHost.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can also use `[TestFixtureSetUp]/[TestFixtureTearDown]` so it's only created/disposed once per test fixture instead of every test.

Answer (score 0):

This error is a result of trying to run multiple AppHosts per AppDomain. Each ServiceStack AppHost is a singleton and only allows a single AppHost per AppDomain.